# Update a String list column in Cassandra DB with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm new on Cassandra and Scala, I'm working on a Kafka consumer (written in Scala) that has to update a field of a row on Cassandra from data it receives.
And so far no problem.

In this row a field is a String list and when I do the update this field hasn't to change, so I have to assign the same String list to it self.

```
UPDATE keyspaceName.tableName
SET fieldToChange = newValue
WHERE id = idValue
AND fieldA = '${currentRow.getString("fieldA")}'
AND fieldB = ${currentRow.getInt("fieldB")}
...
AND fieldX =  ${currentRow.getList("fieldX", classOf[String]).toString}
...
```

But I receive even the exception:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 19:49 no viable alternative at input ']' (... 482                   AND fieldX =  [[listStringItem1]]...)
```

I currently haven't found anything that could help me through the web

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Scala's string representation of the list doesn't match to the [Cassandra's representation of the list](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useInsertList.html), so it generates errors.

Instead of constructing the CQL statement directly in your code, it's better to use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/statements/prepared/) and bind variables to it:

1. first, it will speedup the execution as Cassandra won't parse every statement separately;
2. it will be easier to bind variables as you won't need to care about corresponding string representation

But be very careful with Scala - Java driver expects Java's lists, sets, maps, and base types, like, ints, etc.. You may look to [java-driver-scala-extras package](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver-scala-extras), but you'll need to compile it yourself, as it's not available on Maven Central.

Comment: I would not use any driver/lib, I can't alter the server.
In addition if I'll do I have to alter a lot of stuff in my classes.
Is there a way to prepare the string list to be injected into the Update script?

Comment: How you'll access Cassandra from Scala without using the driver? Are you issuing commands via `cqlsh`?

Comment: if you don't want to use anything else, just format text correctly - I've put into answer the link to example how string list should be formatted...